# Walkthrough for setting up Proxy Server using Squid on Windows

Tags: windows, proxy, internet, webfilter

Some of the employees are using the internet for non-work related activity (accessing naughty websites, online shopping, MySpace etc.. etc.. after business hours). I would like to stop internet abuse and be aware of how bandwidth is being used. I want to be able to view top visited websites, search engine queries as well as disable IM and P2P protocols.

I would really appreciate it if someone showed me how to set up *Squid* on a Windows box, add rules, create reports and direct users into the new proxy server.

and as always, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with the Windows version, but [`the webalizer`](http://www.webalizer.org/) can analyze Squid logs and generate the statistics you are looking for.

> The Webalizer is a fast, free web server log file analysis program. It produces highly detailed, easily configurable usage reports in HTML format, for viewing with a standard web browser.
>
> ...
>
> Handles standard Common  logfile format (CLF) server logs, several variations of the NCSA Combined  logfile format, wu-ftpd/proftpd  xferlog (FTP) format logs,  **Squid proxy server native format**, and W3C Extended log formats. In addition, gzip (.gz) and bzip2 (.bz2) compressed logs may be used directly without the need for uncompressing.

The download page contains a reference to a windows port (uses included `Cygwin dll`).

Answer (score 0):

I found this by searching google with a very basic questions.
www.reaper-x.com/2006/07/18/complete-guide-on-installing-and-configuring-squid-proxy-server-for-windows/

Comment: Thanks but this is not, umm, user-friendly guide. I really didn't get it.